# Problemas de sincronia ao compartilhar objetos com Factory e $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Estou tentando fazer uma listagem de lugares por bairro. Estes dados vem de URLs diferentes:

`www.example.com/api/lugares/bairro/1`

`www.example.com/api/lugares/bairro/2`

o `ID` do bairro é gerada em um controller `BairrosCtrl`, que é onde o usuário seleciona o bairro:

```
app.controller('BairrosCtrl', function($scope, selectedBairro, $location) {
    $scope.escolhaLugar = function(bairro) {
        $scope.$watch('bairro', function(newBairro) {
            if(newBairro) {
                selectedBairro.set(newBairro);
            }
        });
        $location.path('/lugares/');
    };
});
```

Note que o bairro é passado por parâmetro na função `escolhaLugar(bairro)`;

Usando a Factory `selectedBairro` para tentar **compartilhar o objeto bairro** eu crio: uma variável pra inicializar, um método GET e outro SET:

```
app.factory('selectedBairro', function(){
    var bairro = {}
    return {
        set: function(bairroSelecionado) {
            bairro = bairroSelecionado;
        },
        get: function() {
            return bairro;
        }
    };
});
```

Pra tentar consumir o dado **compartilhado** que vem da função GET eu uso a seguinte função ($watch) no controller `LugaresCtrl`:

```
app.controller('LugaresCtrl', function($scope, serviceLugares, $location, selectedBairro) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return selectedBairro.get();
    }, function(newBairro) {
        if(newBairro) {
            $scope.bairro = newBairro;
            debugger; /*DEBUGGER 1*/
        }
    });
    debugger; /*DEBUGGER 2*/
    serviceLugares.getLugares($scope.bairro.id, function(data) {
        $scope.lugares = data.lugares;
    });
});
```

Vendo que `$scope.bairro = newBairro` eu passo `$scope.bairro.id` por parâmetro para concatenar com o restante da URL na Factory `serviceLugares`, que é a responsável pela requisição $http que acessa a API:

```
app.factory('serviceLugares', function($http){
    var lugaresList,
        obj = {};
    obj = {
        getLugares:function(id, callback) {
            if(lugaresList) {
                callback(lugaresList);
                return false;
            } 
            else {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://www.example.com/api/lugares/bairro/' + id
                }).success(function(data) {
                    obj.saveLugares(data);
                    callback(data);
                })
            }
        },
        saveLugares:function(data) {
            lugaresList = data;
        }
    }
    return obj;
});
```

**Em `LugaresCtrl` temos 2 `debugger;`. No DEBUGGER 1 o valor de `$scope.bairro` está correto. Porém, no DEBUGGER 2 `$scope.bairro` não existe. PORQUE `DEBUGGER 2` É EXECUTADO ANTES DE `DEBUGGER 1`.**

Alguém me da uma força?

Comment: Não é porque vocẽ colocou um `$watch` em `bairro` que ele será inicializado. Por isso a divergência entre os `debuggers`. O `DEBUGGER 2` é executado na inicialização do controller. Um controller externo ou um atributo deve inicializar `$scope.bairro` para que `DEBUGGER 2` exiba um valor diferente de `undefined`.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, mas já tentei usar `$scope.bairro = {};` para inicializar a variável, mas o valor dela não altera, ou seja, no `DEBUGGER 2` ela é um `Object {}` vazio.

Comment: Analisando melhor, vejo que o `DEBUGGER 2` é executado primeiro do que o `DEBUGGER 1`. Logo, nunca vai dar tempo de atualizar o objeto para usá-lo no parâmetro de `getLugares(id, callback)`. E agora? :(

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Tanto é que usando `{{barrio.id}}` na `view` ele exibe o `ID`. Ou seja, bairro foi atualizado em tempo hábil para usar o `bind`, mas não pra usar no `controller`.

Comment: Exatamente, como o `DEBUGGER 2` é executado na inicialização, ele é executado antes do disparo do `$watch`. Sem saber mais sobre seu programa é um pouco complicado responder precisamente, mas acredito ser possível utilizar `ngInit` passando o bairro como parâmetro.